# What’s the pronunciation for loathed

Tags: pronunciation

‘**Pleaded**’ is pronounced [pli:did]; what’s the pronunciation for **loathed**: [loʊðid/loʊðəd] or [loʊðd]?

Comment: `[pli:did]` or `[pli:dɪd]` in some British accents such as RP. `[pli:dəd]` for the rest of us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word loathed is pronounced

> ləʊðd

Comment: That is the Received Pronunciation in British English; General American has /oʊ/ for the vowel.

Answer (score 4):

From [BBC World Service Learning English](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/youmeus/learnit/learnitv85.shtml)...

> The past tense -ed ending is sometimes pronounced /t/, sometimes /d/ and sometimes /id/. Which we use depends on which letters the verb ends with in the basic form.

As you'll see there, if the basic verb form ends with /d/ or /t/, the past tense is pronounced /ɪd/ (as in *pleaded, folded*). If it ends with /p/ /k/, /f/, /s/, /ʃ/, /θ/, /ð/ or /t͡ʃ/ it's pronounced /t/ (as in *clapped, dropped*).

In all other contexts, *-ed* is simply pronounced /d/, with no vowel component at all, not even a schwa (symbol **/ə/**) in most cases. So OP's *loathed* is pronounced **low-th-d** (or **/ləʊðd/** if you want IPA), but note StoneyB's comment regarding US variation in the actual vowel, giving **/loʊðd/**.

There may be some exceptions to the above, and some other "rules of thumb" I haven't given, but that covers pretty much everything.

---

<sup>/ʃ/ → *sh* as in ***sh**ip*

/t͡ʃ/ → *ch* as in ***ch**ip*

/θ/ → *th* as in ***th**in*

/ð/ → *th* as in ***th**is*</sup>

Comment: I've made a small edit to your answer... I hope I haven't messed up anything. :)

Comment: It's a very small font as well as a "small edit", so I can't easily make out what changes you might have made to symbols there! But almost certainly if you think I got some of my IPA wrong, you'll be right (I'm certainly no expert!). All I can be quite sure about is you definitely did the right thing changing ***OP'd*** to ***OP's*** (and as to the rest, I trust you! :)