# How can I know the correct pronunciation of any word?

Tags: pronunciation

Can you tell me any website which has best pronunciation of the words. I, frequently, find many words,of which I want to know the pronunciation.But, I can't know because of non-availability of any source. thanks.

Comment: Use a dictionary with a pronunciation guide.

Comment: I have an Oxford Pocket dictionary. I don't know how to read that pronunciation tutorials given with each word. Can you tell that?

Comment: There should be a guide in the dictionary itself giving the meanings of the symbols it uses.

Comment: If it uses the IPA (International Phonetic Alphabet) you might find this question useful: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/1400/how-to-interpret-pronunciation-marks-such-as-ldd  Of course this presupposes that you know how to pronounce the words it gives as examples.  Since it is an International alphabet, you might be able to find a guide to it in your native language.

Comment: hellodear2, pronunciation varies greatly, among English speakers. There isn't one pronunciation that everyone has. It depends a great deal on which English you are learning. You should choose one and try to be consistent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cambridge Dictionaries Online http://dictionary.cambridge.org/, is a good resource. It has sound recordings with American and English pronunciations of words.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to recommend [Macmillan's dictionaries](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/) to learners.  They list pronunciations for both British and American English, and they have not only IPA transcriptions, but also recordings you can listen to.

For example, try looking up the word *car*.  You can find entries on Macmillan's site for both [British pronunciation](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/pronunciation/british/car) and [American pronunciation](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/pronunciation/american/car).  In each entry, you can read a transcription of the word in IPA, and you can also click the "Pronunciation" button to hear a recording.

Try reading along with the transcriptions while you listen to the recordings.  You'll be able to hear what the symbols mean in context.  Of course, you can also consult Macmillan's [guide to pronunciation symbols](http://www.macmillandictionaries.com/features/pronunciation-symbols/), including Adrian Underhill's [phonemic chart](http://www.macmillanenglish.com/phonemic-chart/).

Answer (score 0):

I've found this web site helpful if you're looking for information on how people actually pronounce words in different parts of the world:

> http://www.forvo.com/languages/en/

**Disclaimer**

Not all these pronunciations are the "correct" pronunciations, but they are by native English speakers, and they highlight regional differences in pronunciation.

Answer (score 0):

Learn IPA (it's not that bad) and then use the wiktionary. It's free, available online (and downloadable as an app for most tablets), and best of all, has recordings of pronunciations of many words.